# React Airbnb date picker custom year/month navigation unwanted year/month jump

Tags: reactjs, react-dates

I am using react-dates from Airbnb and specified min and max dates, also created custom year/month navigation, but the problem is that if the month is by default before the month in min date and want to change year, it change month and year in both panels to min date month/year and if you click on prev icon it should be disabled and next icon should be enabeld (for example: if left panel month is Jul, right panel month should be Aug) but still it navigates and month and year in both panels are the same

[image]

You can check demo here [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-joliot-vulnk?file=/src/App.js)

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `disableScroll` prop. Checkout [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-http-guj6e?file=/src/App.js) fork of your sandbox